How can I make Melka recognize Petra's death in the Skyrim quest "The Affairs of Hagravens"?
So, I was doing the Skyrim quest (The Affairs of Hagravens) for Melka where you have to kill Petra. I killed Petra and released Melka from the cage, but now she won’t acknowledge that Petra’s dead… I’ve tried the resetAI, disable, enable sequence but it didn’t work. Is there something I can do to fix this?

You should Release Melka first, then kill Petra, do you have a recent save to go back to?

This is a problem with the quest stages. Messing around with Melka won't fix anything. Instead, you have to manually advance the quest:
setstage dunBlindCliffQST 100

Stage information taken from UESP. I'm not sure, but you might miss out on some of Melka's dialog by doing this (as I recall, it's not a particularly long or interesting conversation). I would strongly recommend making a permanent save (not an autosave or quicksave) before running any console commands. This is particularly important in this case, because UESP mentions a bug where Melka may continually try to talk to you after leaving the dungeon, so you really should have a save from before you ran the console command just in case that bug happens.
If all else fails, you can loot the quest reward from Melka after killing her.
For future reference: This bug (quest fails to advance if you kill Petra first) is fixed in the unofficial patch, according to UESP.

If you don't free Melka before she will never know that Petra is dead.
I had the same problem, and since I was playing on console I had to restart the quest reloading a previous autosave. The quest is pretty short, so it's not that bad.
